# How to analyze Time-Series Panel Data with Binaries?

Tags: time-series, panel-data, binary-data

For a project I have collected some data.
The Data has some binary variables (success(0/1), Manager present(0/1), First_Third (1 if the observation was in the first third of the project, 0 otherwise) and also Second_Third and Third_Third and Video (is there a video taping of the meetings). I also have non-binaries like Attendees, Percent_budget_burned, Percent_completion_progress that have any positive or negative (if we have to go back on the completion %) value.

I have a total of >6000 observations for about 200 projects, which vary in length between 7 days on 65 days, every project has a unique ID to identify it with.

First things first: I am a total beginner in Statistics and am undertaking this project in an effort to regain/improve some of the knowledge from my undergrad, which was many years ago so please bear with me.

My Questions:

1.If the success of one project is 1, will I have to put a 1 for all the observations in this project?

2.How do I deal with the first_third topic? Basically what I want is to differentiate the three phases of the project, but I am not sure if having 0 or 1 for the thirds is the right way.

3. How do I make clear (I want to use R) that Date 1 in Project1 is the same Day as Date1 in Project2 (see attached Data)?

4.How do I even start? I want to estimate the influence of the different variables on the overall success rate. 
I came across the plm Package and the bild Package in my googling but so far everything at the computer goes way over my head (I am not that smart with computers, sadly). How do I use those packages? Any tutorials/instructions would be highly appreciated, the manuals from the package-sites aren't really helpful...

A small sample of the data:
[SmallSample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMis8.jpg)

Thank you for your help and your time! Cheers!